# Rails Test & Mocha: How to stub specific model - conditional any_instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-mocha

I want to stub just a *specific* model, but *not* only a specific object and *not* every instance

E.g. Given class 'Person' with attributes 'name' (string) and 'cool' (boolean). We have two models:

```
person_bill:
   name: bill
   cool: false

person_steve:
   name: steve
   cool: false
```

Now I want to stub just steve, which works alright:

```
p1 = people(:person_steve)
p1.stubs(:cool? => true)
assert p1.cool? #works
```

But if I load Model again from DB it doesn't:

```
p1 = people(:person_steve)
p1.stubs(:cool? => true)
p1 = Person.find_by_name p1.name
assert p1.cool? #fails!!
```

This works, but affects *Bill* as well, which shouldn't:

```
 Person.any_instance.stubs(:cool? => true)
 assert people(:person_bill).cool? #doesn't fails although it should
```

So how can I just Steve stub, but in any case? Is there a conditional any_instance like

```
 Person.any_instance { |p| p.name == 'Steve' }.stubs(:cool? => true)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Why not just stub the method generating the object?

```
Person.stubs( :find_by_name ).
       returns( stub(:cool? => true) )
```

I think that's the right (and simple) answer.  I'm pretty certain there is nothing like your any_instance syntax.  You might find something useful in the sequence syntax:

- http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/API.html#M000005

Could you give another example of what you're looking for? Good Luck!

Comment: well right in this case, but my actual problem is bit more tricky. I need it for a controller test where the find method is way more 'deeper' in code. But well, much test approach wasn't ok anyhow so I changed it to make it work. But still I'm curious how to make this work in anycase....

Comment: The cure for deep code is making it shallow :-).  In TDD or good unit testing, you want to avoid complex code and deep nesting.  If it's hard to test, the best approach isn't a complex test for the complex code.  Better to simplify/re-factor the code and write a simple test!